# Case Without Select Case for String Cases

Tags: vba, excel, case, select-case

I am trying to select a different case for each different string combination that can be passed in.  In this case I'm using abbreviations for baseball positions.

To make it easier I have added a String value called "Position" to be what is compared.

I'm currently getting the error:

> Compile Error: Case without Select Case

I assume it's some kind of formatting error, but I haven't been able to find anything online that fixes it.

```
Position = "test"
        Select Case Position
            Case "C"
                If C.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set C = AssignPlayer(C, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "1B"
                If B1.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set B1 = AssignPlayer(B1, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "2B"
                If B2.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set B2 = AssignPlayer(B2, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "3B"
                If B3.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set B3 = AssignPlayer(B3, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "SS"
                If SS.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set SS = AssignPlayer(SS, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "LF"
                If LF.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set LF = AssignPlayer(LF, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "CF"
                If CF.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set CF = AssignPlayer(CF, CurrentPlayer)
            Case "RF"
                If RF.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                    Set RF = AssignPlayer(RF, CurrentPlayer)
        End Select
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: None of your `If`'s have `End If`'s. Either add `End If` to each or make entire `if` statement into one line.

Comment: as @VictorK mentioned add End if to your IFs or use this` IF` condition `THEN:`  statement.

Comment: Or you can continue the line by putting ` _` after each `Then` and make the `If` a single line if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill your new line in your if-statement. They should be a single line as shown below:

```
If RF.DollarPerWar < Cells(i, 8).Value Then Set RF = AssignPlayer(RF, CurrentPlayer)
```

Comment: Or, add `End If` to the line underneath.

Comment: Yes, but that’s not needed unless there’s any else. Less is beautiful 

Comment: I think using a line continuer `_` instead of making it all one long line would be easier to read if you aren't going to use an `End If`.